# Json.net deserialize same objectcts with different names

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I am using Json.net to deserialize JSON data from exist service.
The sample:

```
{
    "id" : 3223,
    "name" : "position 3223",
    "containers" : {
        "container_demo" : {
            "id" : 12,
            "name" : "demo",
            "value" : 34
        },
        "different_name_1" : {
            "id" : 33,
            "name" : "demo 3",
            "value" : 1
        },
        "another_contaier" : {
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "another demo",
            "value" : 34
        }
    }
}
```

As we see, we have same structure and different names of objects in `container` object.
The taget is to deserialize `containers` as Array of `Container` objects:

```
public class Root
{
    public int id {set;get;}
    public string name {set;get;}
    Array<Container> containers {set;get;}
}

public class Container
{
    public int id {set; get;}
    public string name {set;get;}
    public int value {set;get;}
}
```

How to solve it? Is it possible to use `CustomCreationConverter<T>` to deserialize this correctly?

Comment: The `containers` property is a generic type? Detail your classes, please.

Comment: I do not know is it generic on server, but in my C# implementation it is not generic.

Comment: it is typo sorry. i have fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

Given your updated classes and updated JSON, you would do:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Root root { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public int id {set;get;}
    public string name {set;get;}
    public Dictionary<string, Container> containers { get; set; }
}

public class Container
{
    public int id {set; get;}
    public string name {set;get;}
    public int value {set;get;}
}
```

And use it like:

```
        var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Note that the `"root"` property in the JSON requires an extra level of indirection, which us provided by the `RootObject` class.  You might want to rename your `Root` to something more descriptive like `RootContainer`.

**Update 2**

The JSON in the question was modified again to eliminate the `"root"` property, so `RootObject` is unnecessary and you just need to do:

```
        var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

**Original Answer**

Assuming your nested `containers` are also of type `Container`, you can just deserialize them as a `Dictionary<string, Container>` property:

```
public class Container
{
    public int id { set; get; }
    public string name { set; get; }
    public int? value { set; get; } // Null when the property was not present in the JSON.
    public Dictionary<string, Container> containers { get; set; }
}
```

You would use it like:

```
    public static void Test()
    {
        string json = @"
        {
            ""id"" : 3223,
            ""name"" : ""position 3223"",
            ""containers"" : {
                ""container_demo"" : {
                    ""id"" : 12,
                    ""name"" : ""demo"",
                    ""value"" : 34
                },
                ""different_name_1"" : {
                    ""id"" : 33,
                    ""name"" : ""demo 3"",
                    ""value"" : 1
                },
                ""another_contaier"" : {
                    ""id"" : 1,
                    ""name"" : ""another demo"",
                    ""value"" : 34
                }
            }
        }";

        var container = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container>(json);

        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };

        Debug.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(container, Formatting.Indented, settings));
    }
```

This produces the output:

```
{
  "id": 3223,
  "name": "position 3223",
  "containers": {
    "container_demo": {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "demo",
      "value": 34
    },
    "different_name_1": {
      "id": 33,
      "name": "demo 3",
      "value": 1
    },
    "another_contaier": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "another demo",
      "value": 34
    }
  }
```

As you can see, all data was deserialized and serialized successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Try a data structure like this -

```
public class Holder
{
    public int id { set; get; }

    public string name { set; get; }

    public Dictionary<string, Container> containers{ get; set; }
}


public class Container
{
    public int id { set; get; }

    public string name { set; get; }

    public int value { set; get; }
}
```

and deserialize json to this `Holder` class.

```
var holders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Holder> (json);
```